# Entity Framework automatic foreign key population

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there any way to force Entity Framework to populate the foreign keys immediately when an entity is added to the context, rather than delaying it until something else happens with the context?  This default behavior is not very helpful when using data binding to display referenced entities.

Just referencing any `DbSet` from the context is enough to force EF to populate the `Parent` and `Parent_Name` of the added `Children`.  But nothing short of `SaveChanges` seems to force EF to populate the `Reference` or `Reference_Name`.

I'd really like to mark `Reference_Name` with the `[Required]` ttribute so it will be `Not Null` in the database, but if I do that, I get validation errors when I try to call `SaveChanges` unless I've explicitly set the `Reference_Name`, even though `SaveChanges` itself will correctly populate `Reference_Name` if Reference is set.

I'd really like to be able to set either `Reference` or `Reference_Name` and be able to immediately use the other.  Likewise, I'd like to be able to immediately use `Parent` or `Parent_Name` after adding the `Child` object, without having to use the kludge of accessing some other element from the context first.

Can anyone help me understand why EF delays these things, and how I can force it to populate the foreign key properties or the foreign key columns, preferably immediately but at least without having to call `SaveChanges`?  I'd really prefer not to have to fully populate all the properties explicitly when EF is going to correctly populate them anyway.

```
public class OracleContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Reference> References { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SomethingElse> SomethingElses { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    [Key, MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}

public class Child
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), MaxLength(30)]
    public string Parent_Name { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2), MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Reference_Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent_Name")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Reference_Name")]
    public virtual Reference Reference { get; set; }

    public Child Clone()
    {
        return new Child
        {
            Parent_Name = this.Parent_Name,
            Name = this.Name,
            Reference_Name = this.Reference_Name,
            Parent = this.Parent,
            Reference = this.Reference
        };
    }
}

public class Reference
{
    [Key, MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SomethingElse
{
    [Key, MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OracleContext context = new OracleContext();

    Reference reference = context.References.Add(new Reference { Name = "Reference" });

    Parent alpha = context.Parents.Add(new Parent { Name = "Alpha" });

    Child alphaOne = new Child { Name = "AlphaOne" };
    Child alphatwo = new Child { Name = "AlphaTwo", Reference_Name = "Reference" };
    alpha.Children.AddRange(new List<Child> { alphaOne, alphatwo });
    alphaOne.Reference = reference;

    var list = (
            from child in alpha.Children
            select new
            {
                Time = "Before referencing SomethingElses.Local",
                Child = child.Clone()
            }
        ).ToList();

    var x = context.SomethingElses.Local;

    list.AddRange(
            from child in alpha.Children
            select new
            {
                Time = "After referencing SomethingElses.Local",
                Child = child.Clone()
            }
        );

    list.AddRange(
            from parent in context.Parents.Local
            from child in parent.Children
            select new
            {
                Time = "Before SaveChanges",
                Child = child.Clone()
            }
        );

    context.SaveChanges();

    list.AddRange(
            from parent in context.Parents.Local
            from child in parent.Children
            select new
            {
                Time = "After SaveChanges",
                Child = child.Clone()
            }
        );

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:\r\n\tName = '{1}'\r\n\tParent = '{2}' ({3})\r\n\tReference = '{4}' ({5})",
            item.Time, item.Child.Name, item.Child.Parent_Name, item.Child.Parent, item.Child.Reference_Name, item.Child.Reference);
    }
}

Before referencing SomethingElses.Local:
    Name = 'AlphaOne'
    Parent = '' ()
    Reference = '' (WindowsFormsApplication2.Reference)
Before referencing SomethingElses.Local:
    Name = 'AlphaTwo'
    Parent = '' ()
    Reference = 'Reference' ()
After referencing SomethingElses.Local:
    Name = 'AlphaOne'
    Parent = 'Alpha' (WindowsFormsApplication2.Parent)
    Reference = '' (WindowsFormsApplication2.Reference)
After referencing SomethingElses.Local:
    Name = 'AlphaTwo'
    Parent = 'Alpha' (WindowsFormsApplication2.Parent)
    Reference = 'Reference' ()
Before SaveChanges:
    Name = 'AlphaOne'
    Parent = 'Alpha' (WindowsFormsApplication2.Parent)
    Reference = '' (WindowsFormsApplication2.Reference)
Before SaveChanges:
    Name = 'AlphaTwo'
    Parent = 'Alpha' (WindowsFormsApplication2.Parent)
    Reference = 'Reference' ()
After SaveChanges:
    Name = 'AlphaOne'
    Parent = 'Alpha' (WindowsFormsApplication2.Parent)
    Reference = 'Reference' (WindowsFormsApplication2.Reference)
After SaveChanges:
    Name = 'AlphaTwo'
    Parent = 'Alpha' (WindowsFormsApplication2.Parent)
    Reference = 'Reference' (WindowsFormsApplication2.Reference)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you would expect the ID's to be populated when they need to be generated by the database, and can't be generated until they are added to the back-end, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: As Ron said, the database generates the identities, so the records get inserted, the ID gets scraped and your object is updated with that ID.  If you're looking for a way for those identities to exist before the data is actually committed to the database, you will need to use a transaction, and commit it when you're ready for those ID's to persist to the database.

Comment: Ron Beyer and MutantNinjaCodeMonkey, I'm not talking about DatabaseGenerated ids at all.  If you look at the model I provided, all the primary keys are Strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to force Entity Framework to populate the foreign keys immediately when an entity is added to the context, rather than delaying it until something else happens with the context?

**Option 1:**

If you just want to fix the relationalship between entities without saving them to the database hence calling `DbContext.SaveChanges()` then just call `DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()`.

**Option 2:**

EF can automatically fixup relationalship between entites without caling `DbContext.SaveChanges()` or `DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()`. Those entites are called **Proxy classes**. A proxy class is a dynamically generated derived type that acts as a proxy for the entity. This proxy overrides some virtual properties of the entity to insert hooks for performing actions automatically when the property is accessed. Proxy creation is enabled by default for your `DbContext` unless you disabled it by calling `DbContext.Configuration.ProxyEnabled = false;`. You don't need to add that line of code because you need proxy creation to be enabled.

Anyway you need to modify some things on your classes before taking advantage of this feature:

- all properties (scalar, navigational, collection) must be marked as virtual
- all navigational collections must be declared as `ICollection<T>`
- all entity instatiation must be done by using `DbContext.DbSet<T>.Create()` method.
- all collection instantiation must not be initialized into a constructor. Proxy class will take care of the instantiation and will throw an exception if you don't follow this point.

Following this steps your entites classes must look like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key, MaxLength(30)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), MaxLength(30)]
    public virtual string Parent_Name { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2), MaxLength(30)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string Reference_Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent_Name")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Reference_Name")]
    public virtual Reference Reference { get; set; }

    public Child Clone()
    {
        return new Child
        {
            Parent_Name = this.Parent_Name,
            Name = this.Name,
            Reference_Name = this.Reference_Name,
            Parent = this.Parent,
            Reference = this.Reference
        };
    }
}

public class Reference
{
    [Key, MaxLength(30)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SomethingElse
{
    [Key, MaxLength(30)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your click event handler impelmentation will look like this:

```
Reference reference = context.References.Create();
reference.Name = "Reference";
context.References.Add(reference);

Parent alpha = context.Parents.Create();
alpha.Name = "Alpha"; 
context.Parents.Add(alpha);

Child alphaOne = context.Children.Create();
alphaOne.Name = "AlphaOne";

Child alphatwo = context.Children.Create();
alphatwo.Name = "AlphaTwo";
alphatwo.Reference = reference; // Notice we use the navigational property.

alpha.Children.Add(alphaOne);
alpha.Children.Add(alphatwo);
alphaOne.Reference = reference;

var list = (
        from child in alpha.Children
        select new
        {
            Time = "Before referencing SomethingElses.Local",
            Child = child.Clone()
        }
    ).ToList();

var x = context.SomethingElses.Local;

list.AddRange(
        from child in alpha.Children
        select new
        {
            Time = "After referencing SomethingElses.Local",
            Child = child.Clone()
        }
    );

list.AddRange(
        from parent in context.Parents.Local
        from child in parent.Children
        select new
        {
            Time = "Before SaveChanges",
            Child = child.Clone()
        }
    );

context.SaveChanges();

list.AddRange(
        from parent in context.Parents.Local
        from child in parent.Children
        select new
        {
            Time = "After SaveChanges",
            Child = child.Clone()
        }
    );

foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:\r\n\tName = '{1}'\r\n\tParent = '{2}' ({3})\r\n\tReference = '{4}' ({5})",
        item.Time, item.Child.Name, item.Child.Parent_Name, item.Child.Parent, item.Child.Reference_Name, item.Child.Reference);
}
```

There are two noticeable changes in this implementation:

- as said you must use DbContext.DbSet.Create to get an instance of the generated proxy of T instead of using the default constructor which by pass the proxy.
- one thing to know about Lazy Loading is that it check if the navigational property is loaded. If not then it check the database to load the entity. In your case all your entities are on Added state then doing `Reference_Name = "Reference"` will not help your context to lazy load the navigational property `Refererence`. This is why instead of doing `alphatwo.Reference_Name = "Reference";` I did `alphatwo.Reference = reference;` because `reference` is on `Added` state, Lazy Load will find nothing on database.

Comment: thanks very much for such a thorough response that directly addresses my question.  It looks very promising.  I'll do some testing and be back to mark this as the answer if I can make it work.

Comment: Okay, there's still one thing I don't quite understand:

If I just set Reference_Name to "Reference" and then call SaveChanges, the Reference property will automatically be properly set.  However, nothing short of SaveChanges (not even DetectChanges) seems able to force this to happen.  It seems to me that the proxy class ought to be able to detect when I've populated all the ForeignKey columns and automatically populate the proper ForeignKey object **if it's already been loaded in the Context**.

Comment: Other than that, this works perfectly.  I changed Children to ICollection<Child> and I'm now seeing the Child's Parent and Parent_Name properties immediately after the Add.

Again, thank you very much for the great answer!