# How to configure EF to automatically populate child Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

When a parent class is not using a database generated Identifier how can I configure Entity Framework to automatically populate the Foreign Key in the child object.

Example Model:

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

Example Seed Method:

```
context.Parents.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name,
    new Parent
    {
        Name = "Test",
        Children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child {ParentName = "Test", ChildName = "TestChild"},
            new Child {ParentName = "Test", ChildName = "NewChild"}
        }
    });
```

Is it possible to configure EF so that I don't have to manually set ParentName = "Test" for each new Child in the Children list?

**Edit** - Here is the generated migration

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Parents",
    c => new
    {
        Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
    })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Name);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Children",
    c => new
    {
        ParentName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
        ChildName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
    })
    .PrimaryKey(t => new {t.ParentName, t.ChildName})
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Parents", t => t.ParentName, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.ParentName);
```

Comment: why can't you configure the relationship as FK ?

Comment: @Sampath by convention the FK is configured. I added the migration to show it being configured. I'm just wondering if the FK ParentName can automatically be populated by EF when I add items to the Parent Children List.

Comment: Related, possible duplcate: [Entity Framework automatic foreign key population](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904871/entity-framework-automatic-foreign-key-population)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a navigation property to Child class, configure the model and then everything should work

```
public class Child
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ChildName { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; } // <-- Add this
}
```

This is the configuration

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasMany(_ => _.Children)
            .WithRequired(_ => _.Parent)
            .HasForeignKey(_ => _.ParentName);
```

(without Child.Parent it does not work, quite strange behaviour)

Comment: Thanks @bubi I just needed to add the virtual navigation property. That configuration wasn't needed. In my case, I didn't need the navigation property so I didn't have it. EF must populate the ParentName property when it overrides and sets the Child.Parent navigation property.

Comment: I always add the configuration. I'm scared about EF updates :)